# How to determine whether I should split a database table by column?

Tags: database, relational-database

let's say there is a table with N fields. 
There are parts of fields that can be grouped as multiple separate tables considering the business logic.

Should I split the table into separate tables to store in the database?

Example:

Let's say Quora has a table called `answer` which has fields of

`id: INTEGER`,

`question: VARCHAR`,

`content: VARCHAR`,

`liked_by: ARRAY (INT)`,

`commented_by: ARRAY (INT)`,

`user_id: INTEGER`,

`created_at: TIMESTAMP`

In terms of performance, is it good to put columns like `question`, `commented_by`, `liked_by`, `id`, `user_id` into a separate table.

Because when user login, the first page they have is the content feed where they only need to display content with those fields. ( `comment_by` and `liked_by` will be sumed to get a number to display)

And put fields like `content`, `created_at` at a separate table. Because only after they click the title/contect card and enter into the actual question, can we display fields like `content`, `created_at`.

What factors should I consider when split a database table by column?

Comment: Have you read about [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: You've tagged it as relation-database. So you should not have array columns. See @cassandrad comment.

Comment: I got it. I should aggregate the `liked_by` and `commented_by` from other tables to reduce redundancy. Thank you @cassandrad and @TomC

Comment: Probably you got it wrong? If you are going to have `ARRAY (INT)` columns, than you've missed the point of `database normalization` and @TomC.
But that actually could be a good solution performance wise — it depends.

Comment: Thanks @cassandrad. Sorry I didn't state it clearly. I have read the database normalization and the three normal forms. I was not going to have ARRAY(int) column in table. Instead I can create a new table where it stores `id` and `liked_by` and use `agg()` in my query to count the numbers, for example.